# If you facing warning Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified

Tags: react-native, datepicker

I am using react-native-datepicker library version: 1.7.2 and facing warning Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question.

Comment: Note that there's nothing wrong with [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=Type%20in%20your%20answer%2C%20then,48%20hours%20to%20do%20so.), but there really should be an actual question _and_ answer, not just an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a required option and must be explicitly set to `true` or `false` DatePicker
then follow below step:

```
class DatePicker extends Component
         this.state.animatedHeight,
         {
           toValue: height,
          duration: duration
          duration: duration,
          useNativeDriver: false //This we have to add in inside library so you will not get this warning and picker will work smoothly
         }
       ).start();
```